# How to download file from FileCabinet in NetSuite using C#

Tags: c#, netsuite

I need to download text file from FileCabinet in NetSuite. I am able to search for all files in a folder and get back the file size, name and URL. But when I check the 'content' property, it is NULL. How can I download the file locally?

I tried using the URL to download the file using WebClient, but it returns 403 which makes sense.

```
        var result = Client.Service.search(fileSearch);            
        var recordList = (Record[])result.recordList;
        if (recordList != null && recordList.Length != 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in recordList)
            {                    
                var file = (com.netsuite.webservices.File)item;                    

                int fileSize = (int)file.fileSize; // Returns the correct file size

                byte[] fileContent = file.content; // NULL reference ??

                Console.WriteLine(file.url + " ==== " + file.name );

                // How to download the File from the url above??

                // Can't do this, 403 error, below client dont use the same security context
                //using (var client = new WebClient())
                //{                        
                //    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                //    client.DownloadFile(baseUrl + file.url, file.name);
                //}
            }
        }
```

I expected 'content' to contain the file content.

Comment: Can you set the file to "available without login"? Otherwise you will need a valid session in order to use the url

Comment: If you have logged in. Remove the baseUrl from the DownloadFile url string.

Comment: Thank for the idea, but I am not sure how to configure the system to access the file without login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a search, the search results do not include the contents of the file, but you DO have the file id.  Below is an extension method on the NetSuite service to get a file by it's id:

```
public static NetSuite.File GetFileById(this NetSuiteService ns, int fileId)
{
    var file = new NetSuite.File();
    var response = ns.get(new RecordRef()
    {
        type = RecordType.file,
        internalId = fileId.ToString(),
        typeSpecified = true
    });

    if (response.status.isSuccess)
    {
        file = response.record as File;
    }

    return file;
}

var f = ns.GetFileById(3946);
var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), f.name);
var contents = f.content;
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, contents);

Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded {f.name}");
```

Comment: Would you know by any chance, how to delete a file by the ID? I looked for any related methods, cannot find any.